# Is it possible to close a form inside an event handler, wherein the event handler is in a class?

Tags: c#, forms, class, event-handling

I am still studying OOP. I am currently trying to make a movie ticket kiosks wherein you click the button of the poster of the movie you like. Form1 is the mainmenu form where 3 buttons are displayed that is named as follows movibutton1, movibutton2, movibutton3. So basically i wanted to hide the Form1 whenever one of the button is clicked but the event handlers of the button are located in another class. and i wanted the event handler to stay at the class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonPosters();
    }
    private void buttonPosters()
    {
        derClassForForm1 classForm1 = new derClassForForm1();
        moviButton1.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
        moviButton2.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
        moviButton3.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
    }
}

public class derClassForForm1
{
    public void movPosterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button posterClick = (Button)sender;
        if (posterClick.Name.Equals("moviButton1"))
        {
            Mov1 movie = new Mov1();
            Form2 movPoster = new Form2(movie.movTitle(), movie.movSynop(),   movie.movImagesrc());
            movPoster.Show();
        }
        else if (posterClick.Name.Equals("moviButton2"))
        {
            Mov2 movie = new Mov2();
            Form2 movPoster = new Form2(movie.movTitle(), movie.movSynop(), movie.movImagesrc());
            movPoster.Show();
        }
        else if (posterClick.Name.Equals("moviButton3"))
        {
            Mov3 movie = new Mov3();
            Form2 movPoster = new Form2(movie.movTitle(), movie.movSynop(), movie.movImagesrc());
            movPoster.Show();
        }

        //wanted to have like a form.hide() here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a public property to you class `derClassForForm1` as such:

```
public Form ParentForm {get; set;}
```

Then you could modify you code in the method `buttonPosters`:

```
private void buttonPosters()
{
    derClassForForm1 classForm1 = new derClassForForm1();
    classForm1.ParentForm = this;
    moviButton1.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
    moviButton2.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
    moviButton3.Click += new EventHandler(classForm1.movPosterClicked);
}
```

This would enable you to write something like this at the end of `movPosterClicked`:

```
if(this.ParentForm != null)
{
     this.ParentForm.Hide();
}
```